# Hive analyze compute stats query failing

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I'm running Hive 1.0, trying to compute column statistics using the built-in `analyze` command. HQL script looks like:

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;

use db; 
analyze table tbl compute statistics for columns;
```

Which kicks off a map-only MR task as expected. The job runs to 100% for both map and reduce, then reports:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ColumnStatsTask
```

But the job is registered as a `SUCCESS`.

Googling led me to [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8062), but the resolution says the problem is resolved in Hive 0.14. Is there something simple I'm missing in the query?

EDIT: Five and a half years later, I've changed jobs and industries twice, picked up Spark and then abandoned Hadoop altogether in all my workflows, and the world aligned around efficient cloud data lakes that don't require a new query language. Hive is a distant memory for me, but I hope the other answer seekers found sufficient workarounds. I don't think I ever did.